# ASP.NET GridView is not dynamically filled

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, webforms

I am trying to create a dynamically bound GridView in ASP.NET.
The GridView itself I already defined in aspx file. But all the columns and rows I need to create dynamically. SQL DataBind is not a solution for me because I eventually need to perform extra logic.

Here is the code:

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">

</asp:GridView>
```

Codebehind:

```vb
Protected Sub CreateGrid()
    Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable
    table.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Name", GetType(BoundField)))

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While i < 10
        Dim dr As DataRow = table.NewRow()
        dr("Name") = i.ToString()
        table.AcceptChanges()

        i += 1
    End While

    GridView1.DataSource = table
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the rows but never adding them to the table:

```vb
Protected Sub CreateGrid()
    Dim table As New DataTable

    table.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))

    For i = 0 To 9
        Dim dr As DataRow = table.NewRow()

        dr("Name") = i.ToString()
        table.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next

    table.AcceptChanges()

    GridView1.DataSource = table
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

I threw in a few other improvements at no extra charge. There's also probably no good reason for that `AcceptChanges` call.